# <c:when test> evaluates always false

Tags: jsf, jstl, facelets, composite-component

This is called 3 times, for each row once. (example table has 3 rows)

```
....
<ui:param name="rowIndex"   value="#{cc.attrs.rowIndex}" />
<ui:param name="rowActive"  value="#{cc.attrs.activeRow}" />
<c:set var="index"          value="#{rowIndex}"  type="java.lang.Long"/>
<c:set var="activeRowIndex" value="#{rowActive}" type="java.lang.Long"/>

<c:choose>
    <c:when test="${index == 2}">
        ACTIVE
    </c:when>
    <c:when test="${index != activeRowIndex}">
       ${index} - ${activeRowIndex} - INACTIVE
    </c:when>
    <c:otherwise>
       NONE
    </c:otherwise>
</c:choose> 
....
```

Result:

> 0 - 1 - INACTIVE
>
> 1 - 1 - INACTIVE
>
> 2 - 1 - INACTIVE

I would have expected:

> 0 - 1 - INACTIVE
>
> NONE
>
> ACTIVE

I'm quite clueless why the result is so different from what i expected.
So i hope you can help me :-)

Comment: Why did you initially use `[jsp]` tag on the question while you're clearly using its successor Facelets? (as indicated by `<ui:param>` and `#{cc.attrs.xxx}`)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The variable names used suggests that you're using the composite inside a repeating component, such as `<h:dataTable>` or `<ui:repeat>`.

JSTL tags are executed during view build time, that moment when the JSF component tree is built based on XHTML source code. However, the `var` attribute of a repeating component is only available during view render time, that moment when the HTML output is produced based on JSF component tree.

In effects, at least the `#{cc.attrs.rowIndex}` is **always** `null` when JSTL runs.

When you're dependent on conditions which are only available during view render time, then you should be using the `rendered` attribute of a JSF component instead of JSTL `<c:choose>`/`<c:if>`.

E.g.

```
<c:set var="active" value="#{cc.attrs.rowIndex == 2}" />
<c:set var="inactive" value="#{not active and cc.attrs.rowIndex != cc.attrs.activeRow}" />
<c:set var="none" value="#{not active and not inactive}" />

<h:outputText value="ACTIVE" rendered="#{active}" />
<h:outputText value="#{index} - #{activeRowIndex} - INACTIVE" rendered="#{inactive}" />
<h:outputText value="NONE" rendered="#{none}" />
```

Note that this problem doesn't affect the `<c:set>`. It merely creates a EL variable mapping (an "alias"), it doesn't immediately evaluate the EL expression and store its result somewhere (as long as `scope` isn't definied). Also note that `${}` and `#{}` behave exactly the same when Facelets is used instead of JSP. As the `${}` is basically a heritage of legacy JSP, you should prefer exclusively using `#{}` to avoid confusion by yourself and your future maintainers.

Comment: This works. Now i'll take some time why and how it works ;-) thanks for the additional information. very helpfull!

Comment: You're welcome. This answer may help in getting a better understanding: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3342984/jstl-in-jsf2-facelets-makes-sense